# Google form save in excel sheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-forms

I have made a form in table format. I want the input field inside the table to focus on next once it reaches max length. I have used jquery code but its only working with inputs not with `td`. The code is below:

```
$(".inputs").keyup(function () {
    var index = $('.inputs').index(this) + 1;
    $('.inputs').eq(index).focus();
});
```

and the `table` html code:

```
<form>
   <table>

        <tr>

            <td class="custom_header">First Name* </td>

            <td><input class="input" type="text" maxlength="1"  required/></td>

            <td><input class="input" type="text" maxlength="1" required/></td>

            <td><input class="input" type="text" maxlength="1" required/></td>

            <td><input class="input" type="text" maxlength="1" required/></td>

            <td><input class="input" type="text" maxlength="1" required/></td>

            <td><input class="input" type="text" maxlength="1" required/></td>

            <td><input class="input" type="text" maxlength="1" required/></td>

            <td><input class="input" type="text" maxlength="1" required/></td>

            <td><input class="input" type="text" maxlength="1" required/></td>

            <td><input class="input" type="text" maxlength="1" required/></td>

            <td><input class="input" type="text" maxlength="1" required/></td>

            <td><input class="input" type="text" maxlength="1" required/></td>

            <td><input class="input" type="text" maxlength="1" required/></td>

            <td><input class="input" type="text" maxlength="1" required/></td>

            <td><input class="input" type="text" maxlength="1" required/></td>

            <td><input class="input" type="text" maxlength="1" required/></td>

            <td><input class="input" type="text" maxlength="1" required/></td>

            <td><input class="input" type="text" maxlength="1" required/></td>

            <td><input class="input" type="text" maxlength="1" required/></td>

         </tr>
   </table>

</form>
```

And how to submit this form as google form as it has so many inputs?

Comment: What do you mean by "google form"? Are you talking about form created with the [Google Form app](https://www.google.com/forms/about/)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `tabinex` attribute in `<input />`. Following is working example:

```html
<form>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input tabindex="0" class="input" type="text" maxlength="1"  required/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input tabindex="1" class="input" type="text" maxlength="1"  required/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input tabindex="2" class="input" type="text" maxlength="1"  required/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input tabindex="3" class="input" type="text" maxlength="1"  required/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input tabindex="4" class="input" type="text" maxlength="1"  required/>
                    </td><br />
                    <td>
                        <input tabindex="5" class="input" type="text" maxlength="1"  required/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input tabindex="6" class="input" type="text" maxlength="1"  required/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.input').on('keyup', function(e) {
            var input = $(this), 
            nextInput = $('input[tabindex="' + (Number(input.attr('tabindex')) + 1) + '"]');

            // If current input value is reached max limit and if there is any next input
            // then it will make focus to it.
            input.val().length == input.attr('maxlength') && nextInput.length && nextInput.focus()
                });
                });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Vikram  can this worked can you tell me about how use it in google form. I mean I have to save these fields in excel sheet through google form.

Comment: @JyotiRawat, can you please explain in detail? what exactly you want to accomplish. Please share fiddle of your code to understand the issue better.

Comment: I have form with a grid layout(table format) I want to use the form as google form where I can save the details filled by the user should be saved in excel sheet. As i have so many input fields tabindex is getting conflict. So in some input field the code which you gave is working and in some input field it's not working.
https://jsfiddle.net/jyotirawat/jgkvtbbj/

Comment: I noticed, `tabindex` are not defined correctly. For instance, 1st cell for Email field has 700 tabindex , which should be 60.  please check and accept this answer.

Comment: To set the `tabindex` correctly, you need to loop through all the `<input />` and set `tabindex` at run time.